# Understanding lstm input shape in keras with different sequence

Tags: python, keras

I'm very new to keras and also to python.
I have a time series dataset with different sequence lengths (for example 1st sequence is 484000x128, 2nd sequence is 563110x128, etc)
I've put the sequences in 3D array.

My question is how to define the input shape, because I'm confused. I was using DL4J but the concept is different in defining the network configuration.

Here is my first trial code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding,LSTM,Dense,Dropout


## Loading dummy data
sequences = np.array([[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], [[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]])
y = np.array([[[0],[0]], [[1],[1],[1]]])
x_test=np.array([[2,3,2],[4,6,7],[1,2,1]])
y_test=np.array([0,1,1])

n_epochs=40

# model configration
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(3,1), activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid')) # 100 num of LSTM units
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

## training with batches of size 1 (each batch is a sequence)
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    for seq, label in zip(sequences, y):
        model.train(np.array([seq]), [label]) # train a batch at a time..
        scores=model.evaluate(x_test, y_test) # evaluate batch at a time..
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the docs on input shapes for LSTMs:

> Input shapes
>
> 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim), (Optional) 2D
>   tensors with shape (batch_size, output_dim).

Which implies that you you're going to need timesteps with a constant size for each batch.

The canonical way of doing this is padding your sequences using something like [keras's padding utility](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequence)

then you can try:

```
# let say timestep you choose: is 700000 and dimension of the vectors are 128

timestep = 700000
dims = 128 

model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(timestep, dim),
         activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
```

I edited the answer to remove the `batch_size` argument. With this setup the batch size is unspecified, you could set that when you fitting the model (in `model.fit()`).

Comment: Thanks very much for reply. In my case I need to use batch size =1, that means the batch size is one tilmestep (sequence) doesn't it?
However, when I tried input_shape=(1,timestep, dims), I've got this error:
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Comment: This comment is a very common problem and should have some kind of response, if not the answer should be updated.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy sorry about not getting back to this. I dont have to time currently to look at this but try reading this https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/ I try to  put something together ASAP