# Time Series Prediction with LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am a beginner in Deep learning. I am implementing LSTM using the keras library, to predict the weather data, I have train and test data. After removing some variables, my imput data has following shape.

```
('X_train', (117, 22))
('y_train', (117,))
('X_test', (13, 22))
('y_test', (13,))
```

Now, I am feeding this data into the LSTM code below, but could not figure out the input shape, where I am facing the trouble. Given below is the full code for the LSTM that I am applying.

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
import pandas
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


train = pandas.read_excel('./data/train.xlsx', sheetname = 'temp4')
print train.head()
print train.shape

test = pandas.read_excel('./data/test.xlsx', sheetname = 'temp4')
print test.head()
print test.shape

# lagsp has 7 misssing values in train data and rest is tha in all entries and also drop un-necessary variable
train = train.drop(['WEEK_NBR', 'DOS_YEAR', 'sorted row','lagsp'], axis = 1)
test = test.drop(['WEEK_NBR', 'DOS_YEAR', 'sorted row','lagsp'], axis = 1)

print train.shape
print test.shape

train = train.values
test = test.values

X_train = train[:,0:22]
y_train = train[:,22]

X_test = test[:,0:22]
y_test = test[:,22]

print("X_train", X_train.shape)
print("y_train", y_train.shape)
print("X_test", X_test.shape)
print("y_test", y_test.shape)




timesteps = X_train.shape[0]
features = X_train.shape[1]

X_train = X_train.reshape(1, timesteps, features)
X_test = X_test.reshape(1, X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1])



print 'timesteps', timesteps
print 'features', features



numpy.random.seed(7)


from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout


###########################
#   RNN
###########################
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

d = 0.2
rnn_model = Sequential()
rnn_model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape= (117,22), return_sequences=True))
rnn_model.add(Dropout(d))
rnn_model.add(Dense(16,kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='relu'))
rnn_model.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='linear'))
rnn_model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

#batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)

rnn_model.fit(
    X_train,
    numpy.array(y_train),
    batch_size=10,
    epochs=10)

# make predictions
trainPredict_rnn = rnn_model.predict(X_train)
testPredict_rnn = rnn_model.predict(X_test)
# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore_rnn = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, trainPredict_rnn))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore_rnn))
testScore_rnn = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, testPredict_rnn))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore_rnn))

# plot predictions

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(y_train) # blue # orange
plt.plot(trainPredict_rnn)
plt.show()

plt.plot(y_test) # blue # orange
plt.plot(testPredict_rnn)
plt.show()
```

This is the error, i am geting after running the code where, the model is fitting X_train and y_train, with above input shape.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shivampanchal/PycharmProjects/WeatherPrediction/try.py", line 81, in <module>
    epochs=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 856, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1429, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1309, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 127, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (117, 1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding lstm input shape in keras with different sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234504/understanding-lstm-input-shape-in-keras-with-different-sequence)

Comment: If you look around on SO you will find plenty of answers to your question. Your question is also not very clear. Does the code break because you are using wrong input shapes (hint, your input shape is wrong), or you would like clarification on something else? Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234504/understanding-lstm-input-shape-in-keras-with-different-sequence) to see how a good question should be asked

Comment: This is the error, I am getting.

Comment: File "/home/shivampanchal/PycharmProjects/WeatherPrediction/try.py", line 66, in <module>
    epochs=10)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1305, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 127, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (117, 22)

Comment: LSTM in Keras takes a 3d tensor so you need to add another dimension (1, 117, 22).

Comment: While giving input shape- (1,117,22).

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Comment: The problem is not with the argument `input_shape`, but with the shape of your inputs

Comment: How can i make it correct, so that it is exactly, what LSTM needs?

Answer (score 1):

`X_train` needs to be three-dimensional. When specifying the `input_shape` in your first layer, you are specificying `(timesteps, features)`. Then, when passing actual data to `fit()`, you need to pass in a three-dimensional array where each sample has the shape `(timesteps, features)`.

```
timesteps = X_train.shape[0]
features = X_train.shape[1]

X_train = X_train.reshape(1, timesteps, features)
```

This leaves you with a single training sample, though, which I doubt is what you want. Without knowing what your data actually looks like it is hard to be of further help! It seems more likely you'd want to break down your dataset into sequences of some fixed amount of timesteps. Additionally, you'll want to apply similar transformations to `X_test`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this. The datset  contains 22 variables, i need to predict one variable, which is already in y-train. What should provide the input shape, after processing like this.

Comment: Your current input shape is fine.

Comment: Nicole, I have changed the code acc. to you, but getting an error in y_train. while training.